# Can't update SQL column with PHP

Tags: php, sql, cron

I've created a PHP script that is triggered by a weekly CronJob.
If the date of last activity is longer than 2 weeks ago, a field will go red and there will be sent an email to one specific person once the CronJob triggers.

I can get the data that needs to be mailed and it already does. Now I only need to update the field `mailed` to `1`.

I tried the SQL query in phpMyAdmin:

```
UPDATE klanten_potentioneel SET mailed = 1 WHERE naamklant = '$naam'
```

Where `$naam` is obviously changed into an existing name. This query works.

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE mailed IS NULL GROUP BY naamklant ORDER BY id DESC ;";
                            $result = $conn->query($sql);

                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


if (strtotime($row["datumlastvisit"]) < strtotime('-14 days')) {
    $mailNeeded = '1 ';
    //hier de code van mailen
                                        $to = 'fictional@mail.com';
                                        $subject = 'geen actie potentieel';
                                        $message = "Er is nog geen actie ondernomen bij $row[naamklant] sinds $row[datumlastvisit] door $row[naam]."; 
                                        $headers = 'From: noreply@mail.nl\r\n';
                                        // Sending email
                                        if(mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers)){

                                        }
                $naam = $row["naamklant"];


$sql = "UPDATE klanten_potentioneel SET mailed = 1 WHERE naamklant = '$naam'";



  }                                  
else if (strtotime($row["datumlastvisit"]) < strtotime('-7 days')) {
    $mailNeeded = '0';
} else {
    $mailNeeded = '0';
}
//to test if the code is working
echo $row["naamklant"];
echo " - ";
echo $mailNeeded;
echo "<br>";


                        }
                     }
                      else {
                                echo "There is nothing to be mailed.";
                            }
?>
```

The record in the database should be changing, but it does not.

Comment: You forgot using `$conn->query($sql)` again after creating update query.

Comment: Sorry, but where is that UPDATE statement actually executed?

Comment: Hey. thanks for responding!
adding 
$conn->query($sql);
after the query worked. Thanks

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Once you've completed query building you can execute it and get result of it.
In this case you didn't do that after the `UPDATE` query.

Add

`$conn->query($sql);`

after

`$sql = "UPDATE klanten_potentioneel SET mailed = 1 WHERE naamklant = '$naam'";`